# How to remove class using javascript click function?

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".slide_nav").click(function() {
         $(".big_slide_in").toggleClass("active");
         $("#headerMover").toggleClass("left_off");
         $(".big_slide").toggleClass("background");
     });

});
</script>
```

so I want to click on the class "background" would erase class "active" and "left_off"? Thank you so much!

I am not speak english, sorry.

Comment: Do you mean click on an object with class background? Or are you saying that you click on slide_nav which has a class called background?

Comment: No, I want to click on the class "background" would erase class "active" and "left_off"

Comment: What do you mean by "click on the class "background"? Do you mean clicking on an object which has css class set to "background"?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slide_nav").click(function () {
        $(".big_slide_in").toggleClass("active");
        $("#headerMover").toggleClass("left_off");
        $(".big_slide").toggleClass("background");
    });

    $(".big_slide").click(function () {
        //check if background class is added
        if ($(this).hasClass('background')) {
            $(".big_slide_in").removeClass("active");
            $("#headerMover").removeClass("left_off");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jn8zzLjm/)

Comment: no, i mean: When i click to "slide_nav" -> "big_slide_in" add "active", "#headerMover" add "left_off", "big_slide" add "background". Then i click to "background" -> "big_slide_in" remove "active", "#headerMover" remove "left_off", "big_slide" remove "background". Thanks!

Comment: @MCN what do you mean by background... do you mean the `big_slide` element - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jn8zzLjm/2/